# can current browsers (Edge, Firefox) recognize a non-canonical top level domain?

Tags: firefox, browser, microsoft-edge

The top level domain within my LAN is, not very originally, *.lan. However, if I point a browser to an internal address such as "printer1.lan", it will not recognize it as a URL but rather bring up a search. Is there a way to teach non-canonical top level domain to current-generation browsers?

Comment: You could turn off searching from the _address_ bar. That way the browser doesn't have to second-guess what you entered.

Comment: probably you need to indicate the protocol, such as `http://printer1.lan` so you won't trigger the search mechanism

Comment: yes, explicitly specifying the protocol works, of course. I was wondering whether there's a way to add any arbitrary top-level domain to the list of domains known to the browser